# Java Logging API for Detailed (and multiline) Logs

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, log4j2, jboss-logging

I'd like find an API that will allow me to provide a specific **canonical set** of information in all of my critical log points of my application. More specifically, it would be a multi-line message with the following information (in addition to the basics):

1. Logging Category
2. Short Description Title
3. Description
4. Response Action (damage control) my application will take
5. Details (exception information, etc.)

With a single multi-line log looking, for example, like so:

```
2017-11-10 14:26:59,156 [main] WARN o.s.t.c.s.ExampleClass:
    Caption: Unconformable data
    Description: The data provided from the X datasource in order to perform Y operation could not be translated
    Response Action: Application will discard unusable data into this component's DLQ
    Details: The data string "x" was not of expected Integer type
        <Some stacktrace>....
```

This is a verbose statement that would be very informative about exactly what occurred, where it occurred, and what the application is doing in response to the event of the exception.

The closest I could find was the JBoss logging API and an example of some code I found in the [ActiveMQ Artemis source](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-commons/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/logs/ActiveMQUtilLogger.java).
The message format declaration can be defined in a single file like so:

```
   @LogMessage(level = Logger.Level.WARN)
   @Message(id = 202008, value = "Failed to check Address list {0}.",
      format = Message.Format.MESSAGE_FORMAT)
   void failedToParseAddressList(@Cause Exception e, String addressList);
```

And one would log a [line with this message](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-commons/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/NetworkHealthCheck.java) in their code by writing:

```
ActiveMQUtilLogger.LOGGER.failedToParseAddressList(e, addressList);
```

That's the closest I could find to what I was looking for. Very cool. However, I'm not using JBoss (and also don't want to lock into that API).

I can use LOG4J, which has a [StructuredDataMessage and Structured Data Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#StructuredDataLookup) which can be used in a Layout, and I'll by default end up using that; my code could delegate to some `StructuredDataMessage` factory to solve this. However, it's a little bit bulkier than using something like this JBoss API.

**Does anyone have any suggestions for this problem -- whether it's another API, a code patterns, or a nifty trick?**

Comment: Are you running in some kind of container? You could likely do it with a pattern, but it would likely depend on the log manager you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't stated any specific reasons why you wouldn't use log4j2 so I'd suggest going that route. As you point out it provides the `StructuredDataMessage` which you can use to fit your needs. Although in this case I would suggest using `MapMessage` since your example didn't include things like `id` and `type` which are built into the `StructuredDataMessage` class.

Here's some quick sample code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MapMessage;

public class MapMessageExample {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        log.info(buildMsg("My title", "This is the description", 
                "No response needed", "Some details here"));        
    }

    // This could be moved into a factory class
    public static MapMessage buildMsg(String title, String description, 
            String responseAction, String details)
    {
        MapMessage mapMsg = new MapMessage();
        mapMsg.put("title", title);
        mapMsg.put("desc", description);
        mapMsg.put("response", responseAction);
        mapMsg.put("details", details);
        return mapMsg;
    }
}
```

and a log4j2.xml configuration file to go along with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%M] %-5level %logger{36}%n\tCaption: ${map:title}%n\tDescription: ${map:desc}%n\tResponse Action: ${map:response}%n\tDetails: ${map:details}%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is some sample output:

```
00:40:45.810 [main] INFO  example.MapMessageExample
    Caption: My title
    Description: This is the description
    Response Action: No response needed
    Details: Some details here
```

Some final thoughts:

> my code could delegate to some StructuredDataMessage factory to solve this

I agree, the factory pattern would be a good choice here. As I commented in the sample code you could move the `buildMsg` method to a factory class.

> However, it's a little bit bulkier than using something like this JBoss API.

I don't really see how it's any bulkier. If you find that most of the time only one or two of the items in the `MapMessage` are changing you could easily write very specific methods similar to the API you mentioned. To add to the above example:

```
public static MapMessage reallySpecificLogMessage(String details){
    return buildMsg("My specific message title", "My specific description",
            "My specific response action", details);
}
```

You would probably want to assign constants to the strings being used in this method, but as I said this is just a quick example.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd use it just like this, but wanted to see if there was anything else out there/other ideas. Thanks